# Deno evaluate expression/script into memory

Tags: deno

Is there currently a way in Deno to evaluate a value? If I had a long string with a compacted script, could I evaluate and initialize its logic into say a function? This would be helpful for more dynamic scripting. If an eval specifically isn't possible is there a preferred way? I don't want to have to use the CLI or pipe values into the program.

Comment: I didn't understand your question.

Comment: You mean like [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) in Javascript but more in a Deno-like way? Yay would love that, too 

Answer (score 1):

There is an `eval()` function available in Deno though I could not find it in the documentation.

Try this:

```
deno run "console.log(eval('1 + 1'))"
```

I believe it behaves like its [JavaScript counterpart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), and here is the TypeScript definition I could fine:

```
/**
 * Evaluates JavaScript code and executes it.
 * @param x A String value that contains valid JavaScript code.
 */
declare function eval(x: string): any;
```